# Redirecting or appending to /dev/null

Tags: dev-null

`>/dev/null` or `>>/dev/null`?
I understand the difference when writing (to) a regular file. But when it comes to `/dev/null`? Comments? Advices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the behaviour for redirecting to `/dev/null` via either redirect `>` or append `>>` is identical. A quick test shows that it also makes no difference timing wise:

Content to print:

```py
for i in range(10**4):
    print("content")
```

Test time command:

```sh
 time python printlots.py >> /dev/null ; time python printlots.py > /dev/null
```

Result:

```sh
$ time python printlots.py >> /dev/null ; time python printlots.py > /dev/null

real    0m0.094s
user    0m0.047s
sys     0m0.047s

real    0m0.096s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.063s
```

So it won't make a measureable difference which you use. It seems the reason both work is to enable developers to use `/dev/null` in their code with more flexibility. If you have a program where one input parameter is the output file it prints to, and append is your default mode, not having append to `/dev/null` would mean you'd have to check first what the target file is. [At least that's what this answer assumes](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-reason-to-use-append-over-overwrite-when-redirecting-output-to-dev-null).

Comment: Interesting answer and link, thank you. But I had something else in mind: would there be any conflict if 2 processes throw data to /dev/null at the very same moment, either using same redirection or append, or each a different one?

Comment: With bash you can test this by calling one task as background process like this: `time python printlots.py >> /dev/null & time python printlots.py > /dev/null` connecting the 2 calls with `&`.

Spoiler: No :)